# Create image with name without blur in the different sizes swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

[image: ScreenShot]

**The screenshot is taken from a 14Pro iPhone.**

[image: ScreenShot]

I need to display a profile pic of every user corresponding to his name in a UITableView.

**Code:-**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imgName: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imgName.image = returnUserNameLetters(name: "B L")
}

func returnUserNameLetters(name: String?) -> UIImage? {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
    nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
    nameLabel.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 60/255, green: 160/255, blue:89/255, alpha: 1)
    nameLabel.textColor = .white
    nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    var initials = ""
    if let initialsArray = name?.components(separatedBy: " ") {
        if let firstWord = initialsArray.first {
            if let firstLetter = firstWord.first {
                initials += String(firstLetter).capitalized}
        }
        if initialsArray.count > 1, let lastWord = initialsArray.last {
            if let lastLetter = lastWord.first { initials += String(lastLetter).capitalized
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
    nameLabel.text = initials
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frame.size)
    if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        nameLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
        let nameImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return nameImage
       }
    return nil
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to create the same image without blur in the different frames as the original image(first screenshot)?

Can someone please explain to me create the same image without blur in the different frames, I've tried to draw these waves but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The image is blurry because you are drawing a very small, 50x50 image. You just need to draw a bigger image.

A simple solution would be to not hard code the frame of the label, and instead give a large font size, and then use `sizeToFit` to figure the frame out.

```
let nameLabel = UILabel()
...
nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 200) // make this even larger for an larger image
...
nameLabel.text = initials
nameLabel.sizeToFit()
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(nameLabel.frame.size)
...
// you seem to have forgotten to call UIGraphicsEndImageContext() in your code
```

Alternatively, draw the name manually. This allows for more finer-grained control over what is drawn. You can e.g. add some padding around the text.

```
// I've omitted the code for getting the initials.
// this is just a function that produces an image from a string
func image(for string: String) -> UIImage {
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 300) // choose your font
    let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paraStyle.alignment = .center
    let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: _] = [
        .font: font,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.white, // choose your text color
        .paragraphStyle: paraStyle
    ]
    let textSize = string.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                             attributes: attrs,
                                             context: nil).size
    let imageWidth = max(textSize.width, textSize.height) + 100 // padding
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageWidth)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)
    UIColor.systemGreen.setFill() // choose your background color
    UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize))
    let textRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize)
        .insetBy(dx: (imageSize.width - textSize.width) / 2, dy: (imageSize.height - textSize.height) / 2)
    (string as NSString).draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: attrs)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ...
  let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
  ...
  nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 250)
  ...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I first copied and pasted his codes, then removed the rest to provide a better and clearer vision to see what lines of codes must be changed. in my opinion it was more clearer. But you are right. I'm gonna write the whole code for my future answers.

Comment: I don't mean you need to include more code. I just mean explaining what you are doing here would be helpful. For example, you can see the answer above yours has code too, but at least in between some of it is explained to contextualize what is going on. This would be a bit more helpful :)